# Java MVC Database controller class

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jdbc, static

I am trying to set up a Database controller class that can be referenced from any number of other controller classes. I am getting the `non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context` error. I can't understand why, as both my classes are non-static. But I was thinking maybe a Connection class is static?

Here is my Connection Controller:

```
package Controllers;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class DBConnectionController {

private Connection conn;

public Connection getConnectionPPDB(int DatabaseCode) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
        props.load(fis);
        Class.forName(props.getProperty(DatabaseCode + "DB_DRIVER_CLASS"));
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(props.getProperty(DatabaseCode + "AGDB_URL"),
                props.getProperty(DatabaseCode + "DB_USERNAME"),
                props.getProperty(DatabaseCode + "DB_PASSWORD"));
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AppViewController.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
    return conn;
}
```

So What I would like to do is call this connection from another controlleras such:

```
public ListModel getTemplateCustomers() {
    try {
        DBConnectionController.getConnectionPPDB(VM_ID);
        try {
            //will be filled with a query and rs
            }
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This class calls the connection with an integer and it returns the connection. But the problem is the non-static error. Can somebody explain why my Connection controller is static?

Comment: Where is the _getConnectionPPDB_ method ?

Comment: @Berger Edited to match described function.

Comment: Ok, so you have an answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The row

```
DBConnectionController.getConnectionPPDB(VM_ID);
```

try to call a static method `getConnectionPPDB` in the class `DBConnectionController`, but it **is not static** .

So you can:

- Create an instance of `DBConnectionController` and call `getConnectionPPDB` on the instance
- make `static` the `getConnectionPPDB` method